# LWC deployment Error while deploying from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hi I am having issue while deploying the new created LWC component from the VS Code to my dev hub org.

Please find the error as below :

```
19:18:39.577 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\Users\ABHIJEET KUMAR\Downloads\OCT\Documents\TrailheadBasic\HelloWordLightningComponent\force-app\main\default --json --loglevel fatal
```

19:18:44.413 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\Users\ABHIJEET KUMAR\Downloads\OCT\Documents\TrailheadBasic\HelloWordLightningComponent\force-app\main\default --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1

```
SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run
```

Error is here :

```
MissingMessageError: Missing message mdapi_deploy:mdDeployCommandCliCheckOnly for locale en_US.
at Messages.getMessageWithMap (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/messages.js:277:19)
at Messages.getMessage (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/core/lib/messages.js:261:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/commands/force/source/deploy.js:38:36)
at Module._compile (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
at LazyLoader.loadModule (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/lazy-require/lib/LazyLoader.js:139:21)
at Function._load (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@salesforce/lazy-require/lib/LazyLoader.js:115:29)
at require (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
at fetch (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js:111:21)
at Plugin.findCommand (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js:125:21)
at Object.load (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/plugin.js:58:72)
at Config.runCommand (C:/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/client/node_modules/@oclif/config/lib/config.js:149
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few steps to cross-check before deploying to org.

(1) Make sure your org is on API version 45.0 or above
Log into the target org where you're trying to deploy, go on setup --> Apex Classes --> New and click on the Version Settings" tab. If the default version you can select is 45.0 or above, awesome; otherwise, you may have to wait until your org instance is upgraded (or spin a new trailhead playground).

(2) Install upgrades to the salesforcedx CLI
On your terminal or cmd.exe, run sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest
You shouldn't have to install the pre-release plugins after February 9th, but if so you could run

sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release

(3) Make sure your lightning web component API version AND your overall project API version is 45.0 (or latest)
in Visual Studio Code, open the following files:

In the root folder:
sfdx-project.json and make sure that "sourceApiVersion": "45.0".

In the lwc component folder:
helloWorld.js-meta.xml and make sure that the API version is 45.0

Then re-run the command deploy source to Org and it should work (it reads the overall API version of the output from the root folder project definition).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that component name is not duplicate in your Org.Check is there any lightning or lightning Web component already exist with same name.

If component already exist in your org, then change the component name and try to deploy.

I got similar error and resolved with above mentioned solution. I hope it will help you too..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there aren't any files with the same name, As if you created a 'Hello World' Lightning component, and you're trying to create another with the same name. This may lead to errors while deploying, and the error details might not be displayed with the error.